# How to create a virtual repository that is mapped to a cocoapods repo in Artifactory/jfrog.io?

Tags: cocoapods, artifactory

Is it possible with jfrog.io and a SaaS account to setup a virtual Repository that is mapped to a Cocoapods type repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible in Artifactory (On premise or SaaS).
You can only create local and remote repositories.

What you can do in order to work with several repositories in your Podfile is to add your local repository to your cocoapods configuration:
pod repo-art add  http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/pods/

Then add your remote:
pod repo-art add  http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/pods/

And in your Podfile add both of those repositories by adding it to the 'plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources =>' section.

For example, this is how your Podfile declaration will look like:
plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources => [
  'cocoapods-local-repo',
  'cocoapods-remote-repo'
]

The 'cocoapods-xxxx-repo' names should be replaced by the names you gave to the repositories upon adding it to the cocoapods configuration ('local_specs_repo_name'/'remote_specs_repo_name').

You can read more on working with cocoapods and Artifactory [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories).